# What does it mean if a regression model is not significant, but individual variables are?

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models

With a logistic regression model of 3 independent variables, one of the variables is significant while the other two are not. The significant variable is my variable of interest while the other two are control variables (age and gender). The model is not significant either.

The aim is to answer whether or not my variable of interest increases the odds of outcome y independent of age and gender.

What does this mean for the interpretation of the model?

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer Whuber, I only found a similar thread about model being significant but variables not. Apologize.

Comment: It's not always easy to find duplicates.  I came across this one by including "significant," "not", and "F" in my search terms--and I wouldn't expect most people to use the latter unless they already had a sense of the answer.